# Notes and remarks over the GUI

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface

I am developing a flex application for collaborative data analysis. To present the data my application  uses standard and custom components (grids, charts etc.).

I want to deliver the feature that allows users making notes over the GUI of my application. So, other users will see they notes late on.

At the moment my question is: How can be implemented mechanism that allows making notes over the GUI? All suggestions and examples are welcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, actually my problem is much easier then I expected (thank for great design of Flex).

I decided to utilize PopUpManager functionality for my task. It does everything I need at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to approach this.  ( Check out Buzzword, MS Word, and Acrobat all for slightly different approaches of note taking on a document--I assume an application GUI could use any of the same approaches ).

I'd start by saying that the click event bubbles:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:click

So, listen for the click event on every child of your main application file.  When you receive that click event you can provide some business logic as to whether or not you want to add a comment /note on the component that was clicked.  Then you just some "note" component for collecting and displaying the note data.  You an position them based on the x, y values of the click event.

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com! Thank you very much for your reply! Actuallu I was looking for something simple... So, below is my answer...

Comment: PopUpManager is a simple approach, but I can easily envision it's elegance.  I was--obviously--thinking of something more complicated.